# What's the purpose of the promise object that gets returned by the .then() method?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I have read on multiple websites, that the .then() method from the promise.prototype returns a promise. Unfortunately, no source describes the reason behind this.

> The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise. - developer.mozilla.com

Why/When would someone need this returned promise object, how is this promise object related to the original object.

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I recommend Kyle Simpson's book `You Don't Know JS: Async & Performance`. It goes into detail regarding the benefits of promises, beyond the obvious ones like chaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A promise is executed asynchronously, you never know when the then() will be executed.

And a promise can return a promise, this allows you to chain asynchronous events handling in singles lines of code.

Example code given by Mozilla:

```
doSomething().then(function(result) {
  return doSomethingElse(result);
})
.then(function(newResult) {
  return doThirdThing(newResult);
})
.then(function(finalResult) {
  console.log('Got the final result: ' + finalResult);
})
.catch(failureCallback);
```

It avoids the "pyramid of doom" :

```
doSomething(function(result) {
  doSomethingElse(result, function(newResult) {
    doThirdThing(newResult, function(finalResult) {
      console.log('Got the final result: ' + finalResult);
    }, failureCallback);
  }, failureCallback);
}, failureCallback);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: Hey, how exactly are they getting executed asynchronously? Thanks for your great answer.

Comment: Javascript in its single thread executes its code in an asynchronous fashion: some portions of code are executed while others might be blocked, for example, waiting for a response to a network request. The executer switches when events are received, and resumes execution of other code portions when events are handled.

Comment: There's no Javascript executer that switches when events are received then resumes afterwards and there is asynchronous I/O is not blocking either.  That's not how the event-driven logic in Javascript works at all.  Events do not interrupt other running code.  Instead, a running piece of Javascript runs until it finishes executing.  Then, the interpreter checks the event queue to see if there's another event to run and, if so, it runs the next one.  If nothing is running and an event is added to the event queue (by some native code), then that event will be run.

Comment: Yeah I simplified it a lot, it was late... Thank you for making it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main aspects to the fact that `.then()` returns a promise.

**The first** is that you can chain operations like this:

```
a().then(b).then(c).then(d)
```

Because `.then()` returns a new promise, the following `.then()` handlers will not be executed until that new promise resolves.  If b and c are synchronous, then that new promise will resolve when they return and the chain will continue when first `b` is done and then when `c` is done.

**The second** is that the new promise can be influenced by what the `.then()` handler returns.  This allows b, c and d to be asynchronous operations that, themselves returns promises and the chain will be sequenced appropriately.  So, imagine that b and c both return promises themselves.

First you get `a()` returning a promise.  When that resolves resolves, its `.then()` handler gets called.  That will then run `b`.  If `b()` is also an async operation and it returns a new promise, then the promise that `a.then(b)` returns that all the other `.then()` handlers are linked to will NOT be resolved until that new promise that b returned is resolved.  This allows a `.then()` handler to insert a new asynchronous item into the chain.  This is a very important aspect of chaining promises.  `.then()` handlers can insert them own asynchronous operations into the chain and they can even do it conditionally based on prior results or current state.

If `a().then(b)` just returned the same promise that `a()` returns, then all the subsequent `.then()` handlers would not be able to "wait" for the promise that `b()` returns because they would have been linked to the `a()` promise and it has already resolved.  It is the returning of this new promise that allows the function inside the `.then()` handler to influence the subsequent chain because that new promise is influenced by what the `.then()` handler returns.

**The third** aspect is that the return value of the `.then()` handler can influence the resolved value of the new promise and that is what is passed to the next `.then()` handler in the chain.  If `a().then(b)` just returned the same promise that `a()` returns, then all the subsequent `.then()` handlers would just see the same resolved value from `a()` because that resolved value was already set when `a()` resolved which is before `a().then()` has called its `.then()` handler.  These subsequent `.then()` handlers wouldn't be able to inherit a new resolved value from then code inside the `.then()` handler.

---

Let's look at a specific scenario.  I'll use a delay method as a simple example of a function that returns a promise that resolves in the future.

```
function delay(t, val) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(val), t);
    });
}
```

Then, define several different async functions:

```
function a(val) {
    return delay(100, val + 1);
}

function b(val) {
    return delay(50, val + 10);
}

function c(val) {
    return val * 100;
}
```

Now, put them all in a chain:

```
a(100).then(b).then(c).then(val => {
    console.log("all done: ", val);
});
```

Here's what happens step by step:

1. `a(100)` is called.  This calls `delay` (which sets a timer) and returns a promise which I will call `a1_promise` just for purposes of describing things here.
2. Then, because we're doing `a(100).then(b)`, we take the return value from `a(100)` which is the `a1_promise` and call `a1_promise.then(b)`.  That stores away the `b` function as a `.then()` handler function to be called sometime in the future when `a1_promise` is resolved (not right now).  That then returns a new promise which I will call `a2_promise`.
3. Then, because we're doing `a(100).then(b).then(c)`, we take the return value from `a(100).then(b)` which is the `a2_promise` and call `a2_promise.then(c)`.  That stores away the `c` function as a `.then()` handler function to be called sometime in the future when `a2_promise` is resolved (not right now).  That then returns a new promise which I will call `a3_promise`.
4. Then, because we're doing `a(100).then(b).then(c).then(...)`, we take the return value from `a(100).then(b),then(c)` which is the `a3_promise` and call `a3_promise.then(c)`.  That stores away our last anonymous function as a `.then()` handler function to be called sometime in the future when `a3_promise` is resolved (not right now).  That then returns a new promise which I will call `a4_promise` (which nobody uses).
5. Now we're done with synchronous execution.  Note that `a().then(b).then(c).then(...)` was all executed synchronously.  All three `.then()` methods have already been called on all the different promises. But, because NONE of the promises created here are yet resolved, none of the `.then()` handlers have actually been called yet.  They've all just been stored away to be called in the future when the promises are resolved.
6. Now some time passes and the timer created inside of `a()` fires and resolves `a1_promise`.  That then triggers `a1_promise` to call any `.then()` handlers it has and pass it the resolved value of the `a1_promise` which in this case will be `100 + 1` or `101`.  Since there is just one `.then()` handler on the `a1_promise` and it is the `b()` function, it will call `b(101)` now.  Executing that will just return a new promise which `b()` created and returned.  We will call that new promise `b_promise`.  Inside the `a1_promise()` it knows that it created the `a2_promise()` when `a1_promise.then()` was previously called so it knows that when it executes that stored `.then()` handler and that `.then()` handler executes and returns a new promise, then it holds off on resolving the `a2_promise that it created until that`b_promise`is resolved.  In this way, you can see that further execution of the chain is now controlled by the`b_promise`, thus the code executing in`b()`and the promise is returned are inserted into the`a().then().then().then()`chain holding off future`.then()`handlers until the`b_promise` is resolved.
7. Now some more time passes and the timer created inside of `b()` fires and resolves the `b1_promise` with a newly modified value of `101 + 10` which is `111`.  This tells the `a2_promise` that it can now resolve with that value.
8. The `a2_promise` can then call it's `.then()` handler and can execute `c(111)` which again just like in step 6 returns `c_promise` which is not yet resolved.
9. Some time passes and `c_promise` resolves with a value of `111 * 100 which is`11,100`.  That tells the`a3_promise` that it can now resolve with that value.
10. The a3_promise can then call it's `.then()` handler which is our arrow function at the end of the chain and we get a `console.log()` showing `11000` as the final value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the good part of a Promisse.

You can chain a lot of methods where which one depends from a method result (in this case Promisse.resolve) above, for example. Like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining)